# What is best way to draw curly brackets with different length but keeping same size?

Tags: gimp

I found it very difficult. I'm using GIMP but can switch to any Linux/chrome/online graphics software.

[image: like this]

Comment: not a pro, but isn't it just a matter of scaling after you trace the shape in svg?(use inkscape for tracing)

Comment: Is this a technical or an aesthetic question? Technically it should be easy to just write a "{" in a textbox and increase the font size? But aesthetically it is way more tricky. If you want different lengths but with the same thickness you will have to manually draw them! Or find a collection of brackets like the image you posted, but in vector format.

Comment: Please specify *same size.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downloaded SVG from https://thenounproject.com/ - they have a decent collection of brackets, arrows and all kinds of other icons. Then imported my image to Inkscape, add brackets and export.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep the same "thickness" but want to increase the span, you can:

- Create a text layer with a curly bracket
- *Layer>Text to path*
- With the path editor:

  - Isolate the tips by removing a segment between two anchors in the vertical parts
  - Move the tips
  - Reconnect the tips
- *Select>From path* and bucket-fill selection

Result: (top is original bracket from "URW Palladio L Bold")

[image]

But Gimp isn't really meant for this kind of text processing, look into a typesetting application such as Scribus.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this starting from "with the path editor"? What is that?

Comment: @AnIgnorantWanderer See [here](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-using-paths.html). Also [this](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Working-with-Paths) and [that](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Paths-Basics).